# GNU Prolog (glpc): error trying to execute as: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, fedora, gnu-prolog

I'm trying to use the GNU Prolog Compiler to build an executable from my Prolog program like so:

```
$ gplc solution.prolog -o prog
```

and it's failing with a really cryptic error:

```
error trying to execute as: No such file or directory
```

I can't figure out what it's trying to tell me is missing.  Does anyone know?

I'm using Fedora Silverblue 37, and glpc is running inside of a 'toolbox' that is also Fedora 37.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to have been that I didn't have a C compiler installed.  I installed the `gcc` package, and got a different error:

```
gcc: fatal error: cannot read spec file ‘/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld’: No such file or directory
```

Apparently to get that file, I needed to install the `redhat-rpm-config` package.  I found that package name from [this relevant comment on the RedHat bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1636613#c4).

Compilation succeeds now!